# Table cells moving because of not leaving the empty cell

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, html-table

I am trying to create a table where the cells are populated with the expected data.

```
<table style="empty-cells: show;">
    <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Roles</th>
        <th>Permissions</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var userInfo in Model.UserAndRolesInfo)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @userInfo.Username
            </td>

            @foreach (var role in userInfo.Roles)
            {
                @if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(@role))
                {
                    <td></td>
                }
                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@role))
                {
                    <td>
                        @role
                    </td>
                }

            }
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-check"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Sometimes the rol will be empty in the foreach statement, if that is the case I want to leave that cell empty, but instead of that, it is moving the button to that cell.

[This is how the table looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lolz.png)

[Code inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyXu2.png)

Comment: Put an empty string in the cell, perhaps? _&nbsp;_

Comment: No, it does nothing.

Comment: You're inserting one `<td>` for each `userInfo.Roles`. Did you want to generate one `<tr>` per role instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set fixed width to `th` and `td`:

```
<style>
    table th,td {
        width: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Model.UserAndRolesInfo is a collection. That means it may contain n records.
2. Each Model.UserAndRolesInfo will have single record (userInfo):
   In the table, Each userInfo will represent a row.
3. userInfo.Roles is a collection. Each userInfo may have x number of roles.
   The problem lies here. Your table needs to have 3 td for each tr.
   1 for User, 1 for Permissions and 1 for roles. If no of roles>1 then there will be 4 td for roles=2, 5 td for roles=3...
4. Your sample doesn't contain td for Permissions
5. @if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(@role)): try role instead of @role
6. @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(role)) would be unnecessary. try else block.